# sum of roots of unity multiplied by k+1

Tags: group-theory, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, summation, roots-of-unity

I'm considering the following sum:
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n (k+1)\epsilon^k,$$
where $\epsilon=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$. I write the sum as
$$\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}\epsilon}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \epsilon^{k+1}=\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}\epsilon}\left(\epsilon+\epsilon^2+\ldots+\epsilon^n+\epsilon^{n+1}\right),$$
then write it as a sum of a geometric sequence:
$$\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}\epsilon}\left(\epsilon\frac{1-\epsilon^{n+1}}{1-\epsilon}\right),$$
which, after differentiation and using $\epsilon^n=1$, I find equal to
$$\frac{1-(n+1)\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}.$$

But, as I know also that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \epsilon^k=0$, then
$$\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}\epsilon}\left(\epsilon+\epsilon^2+\ldots+\epsilon^n+\epsilon^{n+1}\right)=\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}\epsilon}\left(0+\epsilon^{n+1}\right)=(n+1)\epsilon^n=n+1,$$
which is different than the previous result. Finally, I can do also
$$\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}\epsilon}\epsilon^{n+1}=\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}\epsilon}\epsilon=1.$$

I think that the discrepancy between the last two results (i.e., $(n+1)$ and 1) comes from the fact that $\epsilon$'s form a cyclic group, and $\epsilon^{n+1}$ is like "outside" this group, but the derivative does not know that it should stay within the group. Still, why can't I use the fact that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \epsilon^k=0$ like I did in the second and third method?

I verified numerically that the first result: $\frac{1-(n+1)\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}$ is the correct one.

Comment: You cannot use $\sum_{k=1}^n \epsilon^k=0$ inside the derivative with respect to $\epsilon$, because $\epsilon$ is not a root of unity before the derivative has been taken

Comment: If $\epsilon$ is a fixed number, you can't take the derivative with respect to $\epsilon$. $\frac{d}{d1}$ makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write the identity 
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n (k+1)\epsilon^k=\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}\epsilon}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \epsilon^{k+1}$$ you should make explicit that you only use the value of $\epsilon$ at the very end, i.e.

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^n (k+1)\epsilon^k=\left[\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n x^{k+1}\right]_{x=\epsilon}$$

If $x$ had a fixed value throuhout the calculation, it would make no sense to take derivative with respect to it.